# Laravel 7 - php artisan vendor:publish not listing correctly

Tags: php, laravel, vendor

During the process of updating to Laravel 7 I added a couple of extra packages into the **composer.json** file (under "require" and "require-dev" that are listed in the composer.json file of the Laravel 7 depository on Github but were not added/installed when I ran **composer update** with the Laravel version on composer.json updated.

I then ran **php artisan vendor:list** to list which providers still required publishing. The aforementioned packages were indeed listed, however, so was **every other** package that I have installed (a total of 16 providers and tags.) Rather than giving me the option of pressing 0-16 which provider/tag I wished to publish (zero for all), the operation simply **aborted** after listing them.

I then went though the new packages by specifying them specifically - for example **php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider"** - and they were then published successfully.

I then ran **php artisan vendor:publish** again and, sure enough, everything I have ever published (including the new packages that were now successfully published) appeared on the list and the operation was aborted once again.

In order to get the **php artisan vendor:publish** command to work (without having to specify the provider specifically) I have:

1. Added **--force**
2. Emptied the cache **php artisan cache:clear**
3. Emptied the config **php artisan config:clear**
4. Added a couple of the packages to the list of providers in app.config to see if it would stop they would disappear from the vendor:publish list.

The command still will still not work...

**EDIT**
Below is the full aborted error response:

> [2020-12-16 01:17:01] local.ERROR: Aborted. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\MissingInputException(code: 0): Aborted. at C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:128)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(67): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->doAsk(Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion))
> #1 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(470): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
> #2 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(70): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->validateAttempts(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion))
> #3 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Style\SymfonyStyle.php(355): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->ask(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion))
> #4 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\InteractsWithIO.php(211): Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle->askQuestion(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion))
> #5 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand.php(111): Illuminate\Console\Command->choice(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion), Array)
> #6 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand.php(98): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand->promptForProviderOrTag()
> #7 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand.php(73): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand->determineWhatShouldBePublished()
> #8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand->handle()
> #9 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> #10 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
> #11 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(95): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
> #12 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(39): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
> #13 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(592): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
> #14 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(134): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
> #15 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(258): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
> #16 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
> #17 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(911): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #18 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(264): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Console\VendorPublishCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #19 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(140): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #20 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(93): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #21 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #22 C:\Users\james\Documents\outletdeviviendas\api\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
> #23 {main}

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm asking because I have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`? Perhaps you can try deleting the vendor folder and do a fresh `composer install`.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted your log file after the crash on vendor:publish.

Answer (score 2):

This problem do not specify what has gone wrong so its hard to tackle.It might be helpful if you posted your log file after the crash on `vendor:publish` but you can check the logs for detail error report it will surely help you. The logs are located in `storage` directory. If you want laravel to display complete error for you rather than the cryptic `'Whoops'` message, make sure in your `.env` `APP_ENV=local` is in there and your `APP_DEBUG=true` or you can tweak it in your `config/app.php` like

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local'),
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Also try deleteing `packages.php, services.php, config.php`  manually from `bootstrap` folder and then  try  `composer dump-autoload` or installing the packages again via `composer install` by deleting `vendor` folder.

Comment: Thanks Saddam for the very informative response. I will now edit the original post and add the log response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to Laravel 7 or above
Run The Following command to create a Laravel project version 7

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 Project Name
```

Or if you would like to upgrade without installing a new application follow the steps
in the following link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade