# Laravel artisan commands with input getting aborted instantly

Tags: laravel, git-bash

Whenever I enter a command that requires user input. The command is instantly aborted without me being able to type anything. What could be the reason of this?

[image: example]

Comment: This is something I am also experiencing...

Comment: Sadly doesn’t seem like people care :)

Comment: I made my post 8 months ago. I noticed a useful response today which explained how to check the log file of Laravel for more info. I've now editted the original post to include the full error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133283/laravel-7-php-artisan-vendorpublish-not-listing-correctly

I've followed the advice of deleting the Vendor directory etc. but no luck.

Comment: I have check several sites but this question remains an answered. I don't know why?

Comment: Yep, still no solutions...